# Force Kate to open all files in the same instance

Tags: kde, kate

I have KDE with Kate 18.08.0 installed and I want that there is always only one instance of Kate.
(instance == window)

I mean if currently there is one Kate instance, and I open some file in Kate (via file explorer or in terminal), then Kate (instead of creating new Kate instance and open file in this instance — current behaviour) will open this file as new tab in old instance.

How can I force Kate to open all files in the same instance?

### Update

It turns out that Kate works as expected (open new files as new tabs in old instance) if both

- old kate instance and
- program in which I open new file (terminal or dolphin)

are on the same virtual desktop

So it is still not clear how to make Kate have only one instance across all virtual desktops

Comment: is there a way to have the opposite behavior?
i.e. have new documents opened in new windows?

Comment: @Fabio please ask another question

Comment: diralik I have asked the question already, and actually also found the answer :)  here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72845260/in-kate-text-editor-how-to-open-new-files-in-new-windows-by-default/73184791#73184791

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Kate Version 17.12.3 in Kubuntu 18.04.

For me, if I have an existing instance of Kate running, the default behavior is to open additional documents in additional tabs in the existing instance. This happens whether I click on a file in Dolphin and choose to open it with Kate or if I run `kate .bashrc`, for example, from Konsole.

Looking at `/usr/share/applications/org.kde.kate.desktop`, the `Exec=` line has:

```
Exec=kate -b %U
```

For completeness, the .desktop file with extra languages is this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
GenericName=Advanced Text Editor
Name=Kate
Comment=KDE Advanced Text Editor
MimeType=text/plain;
Exec=kate -b %U
StartupNotify=true
X-KDE-HasTempFileOption=true
Icon=kate
X-DocPath=kate/index.html
Type=Application
Terminal=false
InitialPreference=9
X-DBUS-StartupType=Multi
X-DBUS-ServiceName=org.kde.kate
Categories=Qt;KDE;Utility;TextEditor;
```

Perhaps you could try this `.desktop file` in `~/.local/share/applications`?

`man kate` has this in the OPTIONS section:

```
   -s, --start name
       Start Kate with a given session.

   --startanon
       Start Kate with a new anonymous session, implies -n.

   -n, --new
       Force start of a new Kate instance (is ignored if start is
       used and another Kate instance already has the given
       session opened), forced if no parameters and no URLs are
       given at all.
       given at all.

   -b, --block
       If using an already running Kate instance, block until it
       exits, if URLs given to open.

   -p, --pid  pid
       Only try to reuse kate instance with this pid (is ignored
       if start is used and another Kate instance already has the
       given session opened).

   -e, --encoding  name
       Set encoding for the file to open

       You can use this to force a file opened in utf-8 format,
       for instance. (The command iconv -l provides a list of
       encodings, which may be helpful to you.)

   -l, --line  line
       Navigate to this line

   -c, --column  column
       Navigate to this column

   -i, --stdin
       Read the contents of stdin

   --tempfile
       The files/URLs opened by the application will be deleted
       after use

   file
       File to open
```

**Kate config files**

I have the following Kate-related config files:

```
~/.config $ ls | grep kate
katemetainfos
katemoderc
katepartrc
katerc
kateschemarc
katesyntaxhighlightingrc
katevirc
~/.config $
```

Perhaps you could temporarily move them elsewhere and see if Kate behave properly then?

**Edit:**
In view of the revision to the question indicating that the desire is to have only one instance of Kate across *all open virtual desktops*, the following links are relevant:

- [Bug 371001 - Kate opens new window rather than tab if on different virtual desktop](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=371001)
- [Bug 383125 - single window mode is not respected across virtual desktops](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=383125)
- [Is it possible to respect single window mode across desktops in kde?](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/6qwccd/is_it_possible_to_respect_single_window_mode/)

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer! It turns out that kate works as expected if I don't have virtual desktops (please see answer update). Also I tried deleting Kate config files, but Kate still doesn't work as I want across all vurtual desktops. Could you please test on your system behaviour of Kate if old instance is on one virtual desktop, and programm in which you open new file (dolphin or terminal) is on another?

Comment: Okay, I see what you see with two virtual desktops. On one, I opened files with kate via dolphin. On the other I opened files with kate from the terminal: result, two instances. I don't use virtual desktops but if I come across anything helpful, I'll ping you.

Answer (score 1):

Following the answer of @DK_Bose, I put the this line on ~/.bash_aliases

```
alias kate='kate -s default'
```

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.